# Load multiple tabs data in website using Polymer's <google-sheets> custom element?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-sheets-api

## Loading data from multiple tabs into one page with `<google-sheets>` custom element

I'm using Polymer 1.0 to create a website. I'm trying to figure out the best way to use the custom element [`<google-sheets>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-sheets) to load multiple pieces of data from different tabs into a single web page..

**I've got a few questions regarding the `<google-sheets>` custom element:**

1. What's the best way to load data from multiple tabs into a single web page?
2. Is it possible to load the [header cell data](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-sheets/issues/19)?

---

### Here's what I've got so far:

- **jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/oneeezy/xrz34f9t/
- **google sheet:** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wdYvOljnxE3HVRat4TSfFb6sWU0dYCeGjoPtQMcTiUs/edit?usp=sharing

**CODE (not working all the way):**

```js
        Polymer({
          is: 'sheets-website'
        });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
section { background: #fff; }
article { padding: 1rem 3rem; }

h1 { padding: 2rem 0; text-align: center; background: #f2f2f2; font-weight: normal; border-top: 7px solid #999; }
h2 { margin: 2rem 0 .25rem; }
```

```html
<!-- base -->
<base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.7.0/lib/">

<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link rel="import" href="google-sheets/google-sheets.html">


<dom-module id="sheets-website">
  <template>

    <main>

      <!-- GOOGLE SHEET
      ------------------------->
      <google-sheets id="sheet"
                     key="1wdYvOljnxE3HVRat4TSfFb6sWU0dYCeGjoPtQMcTiUs"
                     tab-id="1"
                     rows="{{rows}}"
                     tab="{{tab}}"
                     open-in-google-docs-url="{{openInGoogleDocsUrl}}"
                     published></google-sheets>

      <!-- Sheet 1
      ------------------------------------------------>
      <section>
        <h1>Google Sheet Tab 1:
          <a href="{{openInGoogleDocsUrl}}" target="_blank">
            "<span>{{tab.title}}</span>"
          </a>
        </h1>
        
        <article>
          
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[rows]]">
            <h2>{{item.gsx$title.$t}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.gsx$description.$t}}</p>
          </template>
          
        </article>
      </section>
      
      

      <!-- Sheet 2
      ------------------------------------------------>
      <section>
        <h1>Google Sheet Tab 2:
          <a href="{{openInGoogleDocsUrl}}" target="_blank">
            "<span>{{tab.title}}</span>"
          </a>
        </h1>
        
        <article>
        
          <ul>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[rows]]">
            <li>
              <a href="{{item.gsx$link.$t}}">{{item.gsx$name.$t}}</a>
            </li>
          </template>
          </ul>
          
        </article>
      </section>


    </main>

  </template>
</dom-module>




<!-- Custom Element 
---------------------------------------->
<sheets-website></sheets-website>
```